# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. Using findpeaks in MatLab

Tags: matlab, data-analysis

I've have been using findpeaks in MatLab to locate the maximum and minimum points of a waveform with no problem, but in the last 20 minutes or so the error:

> ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Has appeared an I have no idea why. Even trying simple exercises with test data has resulted in the same error. For example if I were to have the dataset:

```
test = [ 0.1 0.5 0.9 0.5 0.2 0.6 1.0 0.7 0.3 0.1 ]
```

and used the code:

```
peaks = test(findpeaks(test));
```

I would expect the result:

```
peaks = [0.1 0.9 0.2 1.0 0.1 ]
```

but for some reason this is no longer the case.

Please advise.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Findpeaks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) returns the peak values, not their indices. Try this.

```
peaks=findpeaks(test)
```

If you want to find the local minima as well,

```
peaks = [findpeaks(test) -findpeaks(-test)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but what should I add if I require the minimum values as well as the peak values?

Comment: the minimum values found by your code are not correct. Is there a syntax error perhaps?

Comment: findpeaks can actually return the indices of the peaks with the syntax `[peaks peak_indices] = findpeaks(test)`